# Converting Write-Output to an input as command

Tags: powershell

Basically, I run this application a lot with different launch parameters.
I usually open up PowerShell in the folder of application and write something like this.

```
.\Name.exe -specific -launch -parameters
```

The application will start running, so I'm trying to streamline this a little bit and grab the syntax for launching the application from its cfg file.

What I've been trying

```
function startfunction {
    cls
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
    echo ""
    echo "     Enter Config Name"
    echo ""
    echo "---------------------------------------------------------"
    $name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Config';

    Get-Content -Path .\application\configs\$name.cfg |
        Write-Output -OutVariable launch;

    Start-Process $launch;
}
```

Contents of `$name.cfg`:

```
.\Name.exe -specific -launch -parameters
```

Results/Error:

```
Enter Config: Name
.\Name.exe -specific -launch -parameters
Start-Process : Cannot convert 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to the type
'System.String' required by parameter 'FilePath'. Specified method is not
supported.
At C:\PSM0001.ps1:38 char:17
+   Start-Process $launch;
+                 ~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Comment: Are you specifically trying to allow blank lines in your config file?  You're also going to have to separate the filepath for the exe from the extra launch arguments.

Comment: `$launch=get-content $Path; Start-process $launch[0] @($launch[1..($launch.count-1]))`

Comment: `$cmd, $params = $launch; & $cmd @params`, assuming that `$launch` contains the program path and arguments as individual elements (`".\Name.exe", "-specific", "-launch", "-parameters"`), not as a single string (`".\Name.exe -specific -launch -parameters"`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Does assignment work that way?  Array item 0 will get assigned to `$cmd`, the remainder to `$params`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Exactly.

Comment: Well that just helped me in a project I'm working on.  Thanks for the lesson @AnsgarWiechers

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1

>       $launch=get-content  $Path ; Start-process $launch[0] @($launch[1..($launch.count-1)])

 Was very close to what I'm going for except that launched windows explorer to take me to the folder an not the application :p I'm a little confused on by what AnsgarWiechers and hoping you can break it down for me, please

Comment: The assumption is the first line of your file is an executable name/path.  If not, more logic is required

Comment: That's correct the cfg has one line which is 

.\Name.exe -specific -launch -parameters

Comment: I was able to get the output to be an input / get the application open by 

>
    $launch=get-content .\$name.cfg ; Invoke-Expression $launch

>

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` is [considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). Do not use it unless you have a very good reason to do so. For further help please show the content of your input file (`$name.cfg`). Don't post it in comments. [Edit] your question instead.